# I cant get string message from ResponseBody after send parameters with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

hellow.
i have problem with retrofit.

send parameter with @post :

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("sendSms.php")
Call<ResponseBody> sendValidationCode(@Field("phone") String phoneNo);
```

sendSms.php :

```
<?php
...
try {


date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");


$APIKey = "**************";
$SecretKey = "***************";
$LineNumber = "***************";
$text = rand(1000, 9999);
$mobile = $_POST["phone"];

$MobileNumbers = array($mobile);


$Messages = array($text);

@$SendDateTime = date("Y-m-d") . "T" . date("H:i:s");
$SmsIR_SendMessage = new SmsIR_SendMessage($APIKey, $SecretKey, $LineNumber);
$SendMessage = $SmsIR_SendMessage->SendMessage($MobileNumbers, $Messages, $SendDateTime);

echo $SendMessage


} catch (Exeption $e) {
echo 'Error SendMessage : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

code :

```
 ApiService service = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);

                        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.sendValidationCode(edtPhoneNo.getText().toString());

                       call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                                String message=response.body().toString();//.trim();

                                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, t.toString() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

this code works fine. and The 4 digit code is sent to the phone number.,but message "sent successfully." not display with Toast `response.body().toString();`

i try this:

```
<?php
    $mobile = $_Post["phone"];
    echo "ok";
?>
```

but `ok` not display with Toast `response.body().toString();` and display`okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@e7afd80`

Comment: Try converting `Call<ResponseBody>` to `Call<Response<ResponseBody>>`

Comment: What is the error you are getting.? What response are you getting from the server.? Is it just empty?

Comment: no. not empty. it works with postman and display `sent successfully`.

Comment: Are you getting error in logcat?

Comment: no.there is no error. it works fine. but i want get `sent successfully` message.  that i  echo in php code. the`response.body().toString();` return string:`okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@e7afd80` but it most return message`sent successfully`

Comment: try body().string()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `toString()` method will print the responseBody object and not the actual `String` response you are looking for.

That's why you are getting `okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@e7afd80` in toast.

Try with `response.body().string();` instead of `response.body().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
String message=response.body().toString();
```

to

```
String message=response.toString();
```

better way is add response in JSONObject

using JSON

```
    try {
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
Log.d("===","jobj   "+jobj .toString());


    }
     catch (JSONException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @FarzadKamali see i have edited my answer using Json and also you can check response in log

Comment: thanks. Aalap Patel answer is works. use `response.body().string();` instead of `response.body().toString();`